# exiting the repl console with a background process

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

How do you exit from the repl console in sbt with a background process running?  The following hangs:

```
$ sbt
> console
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).

scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "sleep 10000".run
res0: scala.sys.process.Process = scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$SimpleProcess@67219b8c

scala> <ctrl-d entered>
...hangs
```

ctrl-c works, but kills sbt too.  I suppose I'm looking for a letter between ctrl-c and ctrl-d.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Enter `:q` to quit the console (it will lead to some sort of hanging), and, then, `ctrl+c`.

Comment: Great! Worked for me! BTW, Ctrl+d -> Ctrl+c works for me as well.

Comment: Does it work within sbt as well when you try it?  One problem is that ctrl-c kills sbt as well as the repl.

Comment: Hmm, what's your os? I'm using linux, and ctrl+c terminates sbt, only if I fire it at sbt's interface - not the repl/console...

Comment: ctrl-d works after a res0.destroy in the example...  I wonder if there's a way to trigger some app code on ctrl-d?  then we could manually zap the background processes.

Comment: I'm using macosx, under iterm2.

Comment: (I just upgraded to sbt 0.11.1 too)

Comment: when I try it now, I'm no longer existing sbt.  I see stack traces when I exit, but can live with that.

Comment: `I see stack traces when I exit, but can live with that.` Yep, same here -- something about interrupted thread.

Comment: FTR, it quits sbt on .13, 2.11 and Ubuntu.